# Detected LanMan/NTLMv1 Authentication method on Windows Server 2016

Tags: authentication, windows-server-2016

After running a security scan, I have this vulnerability showing up: **Detected LanMan/NTLMv1 Authentication method**.

I can only find information about Windows Server 2008, or Windows XP online regarding that issue.

How can I remediate this issue, and can this fix potentially create other issue?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to track this down is with auditing. You can enable user logon auditing and then search the security log for Event ID 4624 events using that authentication method. The event will also provide the offending process ID. More details here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4624